# What is the plus-sign in SQLite?

Tags: javascript, sqlite

This is a very simple and broad question.
I see plus signs in a given javascript and I can't figure out what they mean. For example:

```
var _query = 'SELECT column1' + 'column2' + 'column3||\' \'||desc as fulldesc FROM '+tableName+' WHERE '+condition+optionID;
```

I 
Another instance:

```
WHERE this_table = \''+tableName+'\'';
```

What function(s) do those plus signs serve? Thank you for your help.

Comment: `+` sign used to concatenation of string in javascript

Answer (score 1):

This is not SqlLite, it is Javascript code to produce a string which happens to be later used as an SqlLite query.

In your case, the `+` operator is string catenation. So `'ab' + 'cd'` gives the `abcd` string.

I would suggest taking an hour to read some [Javascript Tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/)